# How do I prevent different pages from showing while loading user data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have this application in Next.js 13, I show a different page depending on some variables, but every time it shows page by page until I get to the right one. Can you avoid this with a loading screen until the app knows which page to show?

My code:

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"
import Login from "../../components/auth/Login"
import Particle from "../../components/Particle"
import Plans from "../../components/stripe/Plans"
import { useUserContext } from "./../context/userContext"
import { ArrowLeft } from "phosphor-react"

function HomePage() {
    const router = useRouter()
    const { user, premiumStatus, unlock, logoutUser } = useUserContext()

    return (
        <>
            {!user ? (
                <Login />
            ) : (
                <div>
                    {!premiumStatus ? (
                        <div className="flex h-screen justify-center" >
                            <Particle/>
                            <button onClick={logoutUser} title="Logout" className="fixed top-0 left-0 text-white p-4" ><ArrowLeft className="w-10 h-10" /></button>
                            {unlock && <Plans/>}
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        router.replace("../dashboard")
                    )}
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the code for `useUserContext()`?

Comment: Here: [link](https://codeshare.io/6p1pvo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are requesting user data from the server, which takes some time. You need a mechanism to let your components know when that's happening. A simple state variable in the context can be used for that.

In context

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

fetchUserData(){
  try {
    setLoading(true);
    ...
  } catch(...) {
    ...
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
}
```

To organize this better, I would recommend guard clauses rather than that giant chained conditional:

```
function HomePage() {
  const router = useRouter();

  // Add the loading state
  const { user, loading, premiumStatus, unlock, logoutUser } = useUserContext(); 
  
  // Make a loading component, something fun to look at
  if (loading) return <Loading/>; 

  if (!user) return <Login/>;

  // I would probably make this its own component.
  if (!premiumStatus)
    return (
      <div className="flex h-screen justify-center">
        <Particle />
        <button
          onClick={logoutUser}
          title="Logout"
          className="fixed top-0 left-0 text-white p-4"
        >
          <ArrowLeft className="w-10 h-10" />
        </button>
        {unlock && <Plans />}
      </div>
    );
  
  // All checks pass, reroute to dashboard.
  router.replace("../dashboard");
  return null;
}
```

Comment: You're right... I completely forgot to use the useUserContext to do this. I "learned" recently how to use, so I'm kind of lost still. Thank you.